# SEGV_MAPERR since Android 7

Tags: android

Our app gets crash reports on **Android 7.0 and 7.1 only**.

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
_ZN7android6Parcel14freeDataNoInitEv
```

Our app is using the map and GPS, which may be unrelated, but since I've seen a similar bug report on a different forum - with no answer - I thought I'd point this out.

backtrace:

```
  native: pc 000000000005ce64  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android6Parcel14freeDataNoInitEv+16)
  native: pc 00000000000f8004  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
  native: pc 0000000002977564  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Parcel.nativeDestroy+128)
  native: pc 0000000002976950  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Parcel.destroy+76)
  native: pc 000000000297b4ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Parcel.finalize+40)
  native: pc 000000000068a3a0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize+140)
  native: pc 000000000068a67c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run+520)
  native: pc 000000000065fb00  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+60)
  native: pc 00000000000d1c34  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  native: pc 00000000000de970  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+208)
  native: pc 000000000042e238  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+108)
  native: pc 000000000042f508  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+372)
  native: pc 000000000044ecbc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1100)
  native: pc 000000000006958c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
  native: pc 000000000001dbf0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

Comment: I have the exact same, or at least a very similar problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed by someone else on my project.

***TLDR;* The bug occurred when we sent to the Map a location built on Resume from the standard Location class and GSON serialization.**

Using nothing but standard Google objects, we would store the location in case the app would get terminated. On resume, the app would reload the location object and send it to the map. The way the GSON is built, some fields may be missing, and the Map would crash.

We implemented our own Location object to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to post an answer to this issue. Very much appreciated! I can't reproduce the crash myself, but I have received a lot of crash reports similar to yours on Android 7, 7.1 and 8. It turned out, that I had some code where the Location object was saved in Shared Preferences, serialized with Gson as well. I am certain that this is the cause of my problem.